# How to read an attribute in another class?

Tags: python, attributes, pyside

still a beginner in Python, so be kind :)
FYI : Python 2.7.5, PySide 1.1.2, OSX 10.8
Simple question. I have this function :

```
def openFileDialog(self):
    import os
    path, _ = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File", os.getcwd())
    self.label.setText(path)
    print(path)
```

And I want to use this "path" in another function which does not belong to the same class... I tried different things to display this path in my other function, for example, I tried

```
print(testWindow.openFileDialog.path)
```

but it didn't work. How would you do this...?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to [return](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-return_stmt) the path.

```
def openFileDialog(self):
    import os
    path, _ = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File", os.getcwd())
    self.label.setText(path)
    return path
```

This way you can call it as follows

```
path = testWindow.openFileDialog()
```

and store it in a local variable. Then do whatever you want with it.

```
print path
```

If `testWindow` is the class containing `openFileDialog` you will have to create an instance of the [class](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) first, then call the method on that.

```
x = testWindow()
path = x.openFileDialog()
```

Comment: I added the return path.
My other function is
    def essai():
 import pyfits
 path = testWindow.openFileDialog()
 print(path)
But I get "TypeError: unbound method openFileDialog() must be called with testWindow instance as first argument (got nothing instead)"... What did I miss?

Comment: Edited, assuming `testWindow` is the class containing `openFileDialog`

Answer (score 0):

Change your `def openFileDialog(self):` to `return path`, then you can capture it and use it.

```
path = testWindow.openFileDialog()
```